# How can I use the `find` command in Linux to remove non-empty directories?

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have temp directories full of junk that all start with `__temp__` (e.g. `__temp__user_uploads`), which I want to delete with a cleanup function. My function attempt is to run:

```
find . -name __temp__* -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

If I run the command and there are multiple `__temp__` directories (`__temp__foo` and `__temp__bar`), I get the output:

```
find: __temp__foo: unknown option
```

If I run the command and there is only 1 `__temp__` directory (`__temp__foo`), it is deleted and I get the output:

```
find: ./__temp__foo: No such file or directory
```

Why doesn't the command work, why is it inconsistent like that, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use a depth-first search and quote (or escape) the shell metacharacter `*`:

```
find . -depth -name '__temp__*' -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

**Explanation**

Without the `-depth` flag, your `find` command will remove matching filenames and then try to descend into the (now unlinked) directories.  That's the origin of the "No such file or directory" in your single `__temp__` directory case.

Without quoting or escaping the `*`, the shell will expand that pattern, matching several `__temp__whatever` filenames in the current working directory.  This expansion will confuse `find`, which is expecting options rather than filenames at that point in its argument list.

Comment: As an efficiency and tightness improvement, assuming GNU utilities (since the OP is on Linux), I'd actually recommend `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '__temp__*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf`.

Comment: +1 for suggesting xargs instead of -exec

Comment: @AshishKumar - why +1 for xargs? Is `-exec` not a good feature of `find`? pilcrow, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @orokusaki: `-exec` isn't bad *per se*, but it will fire once for every file that matches:  `rm foo`, then `rm bar`, and so on.  `xargs` will pass many filenames as arguments to its child commands, and so is more efficient:  `rm foo bar ...`  Unless you have thousands of files, `xargs` will probably invoke only one instance of `rm`

Comment: @orokusaki: this is correct, -exec will execute once each time a file is found, which will then continuously fork the external command, "rm" in this case.  however, if you use "| xargs" then find will locate all files, kind of store them in an array and then the whole bunch of array will be passed to "rm" called by "xargs", e.g. rm -fr foo bar qux spam eggs etc.   +1 once again for pilcrow for the explanation of xargs.